# BASH не работает скрипт на debian8 хотя работает в других ОС

Tags: bash, debian

Прописал скрипт
truncate --size 0 /home/var/filename.txt
проверил на windows10 в окружении MSYS2 MinGW
все работало, очищал даже txt размером 1 гб.
Но при переносе этого скрипта на сервер с debian8 не работал как положено.
Он просто создавал копию этого файла и очищал копию, сам главный файл оставался неизменным с таким же весом
если это отобразить, то вот
filename.txt (1гб веса)
и он создает копию
filename.txt (0 веса)

все абсолютно идентично, хотя для копии делается подпись
если это было бы на windows, то показало бы filename(2).txt как копию
НЕ ИМЕЮ ДОСТУП К СЕРВАКУ, ТОЛЬКО ПОСЫЛАЮ СКРИПТЫ АДМИНУ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿Какое имя было у копии?

Comment: @user7860670 о, вы из испании, имя файла было абсолютно такое же и формат такой же. Хотя обычно для копии делается подпись (2)

Comment: 1. «имя файла было абсолютно такое же» — в одном каталоге не может быть двух файлов с одинаковыми именами. может быть у одного из файлов часть букв — не ascii? 2. «формат такой же» — о каком формате информации в файле может быть речь, если он не содержит ни одного байта информации???

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  имеется filename.err файл и filename(без формата), которые на debian, а deb на серваке, при использовании truncate он не очищает файл, а просто создает тот же самый файл только пустой. И они оба находятся в одном месте и стоят рядом друг с другом. Этот скрипт очищает другие файлы нормально, но эти файлы нет

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Сударь, не совсем понимаю ваши слова.

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ ls -l /home/var` до выполнения команды и после. в виде текста. и вставьте, пожалуйста, этот текст непосредственно в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: ещё раз: приведите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ ls -l /home/var` до выполнения команды и после. **в виде текста**. и вставьте, пожалуйста, этот текст непосредственно в текст вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin к сожалению доступ к серверу не имею

Comment: ну, как получите, сообщите.

Comment: Тут скорее надо задавать вопрос почему эта приблуда показывает два файла с одинаковыми именами в одной папке.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос хороший, но я не знаю почему